# Remove entry from @INC

Tags: perl, terminal

Is it possible to remove an entry from @INC from the command line?

I know `export PERL5LIB=/path/file.pm` can be used to add them, but can they be removed in a similar fashion?

**EDIT:**
I know that directories are not typically removed from @INC, but in my case (and maybe yours, if you are here for help) I added an entry of my own that I needed removed not only because it was a custom entry, but also because it specified a file (incorrect usage of @INC) and not a folder.

Additional Info:
The `export` command was executed from the command line, not from a script.

Comment: A thought occurs - why?

Comment: I was trying to determine what led to this question, and perhaps offer a solution to that problem. I don't feel a particular need to guess or convince anyone to take me up on that, so if you're happy with the answer you've got: great!

Comment: "A thought occurs - why? " In my case, our IT department cloned our old Ubuntu machine, and updated the OS on the clone, and now in \@INC there is an invalid directory listed, which causes a program to list Perl modules to crash. To get past this I created the non-existing directory that was in \@INC.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the [`no lib`](http://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html#Deleting-directories-from-@INC) pragma from the command line with `perl -M-lib=...`:

```
$ PERL5LIB=/tmp/foo perl -le 'print for @INC'
/tmp/foo
... normal @INC entries ...
$ PERL5LIB=/tmp/foo perl -M-lib=/tmp/foo -le 'print for @INC'
... normal @INC entries ...
```

---

*Update:* Based on the wording of the question, I assumed that you had a system where you had set `PERL5LIB`, and were asking how to exclude entries once in a while, only for specific runs of `perl` (*"from the command line"*). That's what the above does: The effect of `no lib` used on the command line is only temporary for that run of `perl`.

But the discussion in the comments revealed that it was the opposite: you had run `export PERL5LIB=...` "from the command line" (the effect of which is only temporary the current session/shell), and wanted to undo that change - for which the solution is either to run `export PERL5LIB=` (setting a new value overwrites the previous one, `export` is not like adding elements to a list, it just sets a new value), or to simply log out and back in again.

If you had set `PERL5LIB` in a place like the `.profile` or `.bashrc` files, then you would need to edit those and comment out or delete the entries you don't want, and log out and back in again.

Comment: When I enter `perl -M-lib=/home/pi/NetSNMP/OID.pm -le 'print for @INC'` into the terminal, the output shows that it has been removed, but executing `perl -e "print @INC"` shows it as still being present.

Comment: @CtrlS Yes, any change to `@INC` will only last for that interpreter. If you want to make a permanent change, the best thing would be to remove that path from wherever it is being added, such as wherever `PERL5LIB` is being set. And by the way, `@INC` should contain directories, an entry of `/home/pi/NetSNMP/OID.pm` doesn't make sense anyway.

Comment: It was added via the command line using `export PERL5LIB=~/OID.pm`, so how would I undo it in this case?  Interestingly, the export command seems to overwrite existing paths to the same file name.

Comment: Thanks for the advice by the way!  It is probably due to the presence of the .pm file specified that my "fix" is not working as intended, haha.

Comment: Should I just write, execute, (and delete) a perl script that runs the `no lib` command rather than trying to do it in terminal?

Comment: @CtrlS Where is your `export PERL5LIB=...` command? If you typed it at the command line, simply logging out and logging back in should take care of it. If it's in e.g. `.profile` or `.bashrc`, comment out that line and log out and back in again. If it's somewhere else, comment it out there and reboot to play it safe. I don't know what you mean with *"the export command seems to overwrite existing paths to the same file name"* - setting an environment variable will overwrite its contents unless you explicitly include the previous value, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Yes, it was executed at the command line.  Okay, I will see if it is removed after restarting the Pi.  What I mean is that I had all the default @INC entries, plus my own "/home/pi/some/path/OID.pm" and then I ran the export command again but with "/home/pi/some/other/path/OID.pm" and the previous path to the OID file was (conveniently?) removed.  Additionally, using the export command to add "/NetSNMP/" had no effect.

Comment: @CtrlS *"Should I just write, execute, (and delete) a perl script that runs the `no lib` command"* - The changes made to `@INC` by `no lib` are not permanent, they only last for that `perl` instance. For a change to last, it needs to be made to `PERL5LIB` or wherever else it's being set *outside* of `perl` (like [`sitecustomize.pl`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-f*), but that's pretty rare in my experience). (Of course, if a script includes `use lib ...;`, that'll be "permanent" *for that script*).

Comment: @CtrlS *"I ran the export command again ... and the previous path to the OID file was (conveniently?) removed"* [`PERL5LIB`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#PERL5LIB) is a single environment variable containing a list of directories (*one* string with a separator character between paths). If you assign one value to it, and then a second one, the second overwrites the first. To add a value, one might use an expression like `PERL5LIB="/some/lib/path${PERL5LIB:+:${PERL5LIB}}"; export PERL5LIB;` (depending on the shell).

Comment: Booted up the Pi just now, executed `perl -le 'print for @INC'`, and yep, the entry is now gone!  Your comments have been extremely helpful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can change it in a BEGIN block. Example:

```
$ perl -MData::Dumper -e 'BEGIN { @INC = qw// }; print Dumper(\@INC);'
$VAR1 = [];
```

Comment: Would this allow selective removal of entries without manually describing each one that should be present?

Comment: Sure. `BEGIN { @INC = grep !/unwanted-inc-dir/,@INC }`

Comment: Looks like it should work, but I get:
`Illegal division by zero at -e line 1.`

Comment: @CtrlS I don't get that error; @mob's suggestion seems to work for me - you'll have to show the code you ran. One note though: the regex isn't anchored, if you wanted to play it safer: `BEGIN { @INC = grep $_ ne "unwanted-inc-dir", @INC }` (or just use [my suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50496795/9300627) )